# Prevent Windows 10 update from changing network adapter IP

Tags: networking, windows-10, intranet

Every time I update in Windows 10, it changes the IP of my second ethernet adapter to `10.0.0.1`, cutting off my wired intranet which expects `10.0.0.2`. The whole reason I use this IP is that, originally when I was using `10.0.0.1` for the intranet, Windows update would change it to `10.0.0.2`. I really don't understand why Windows feels free to change adapter settings. For me the effect is not much different than malware... How can I prevent Windows 10 from hacking a DoS on my own machine every time I do an ordinary update?

**Configuration**

- Adapter 1: on-board (physical) ethernet set to DHCP (not changed by update)
- Adapter 2: PCI (physical) ethernet set to manual IP `10.0.0.2` (except after update)

Comment: What kind of adapters are they? Physical or virtual?

Comment: Physical, as appended to the original question.